# Org mode table range excludes empty cells

Tags: org-table

For me this problem occurs when using org-lookup-first. However, I think this might happen in a lot of other circumstances as well. When specifying a range of cells  for example via `@1$1..@>$1` it looks like empty cells in this range are compressed/omitted (`@1$1..@>$1` should select the whole column of a table).
When selecting multiple columns like this this can cause weird behavior, because the two lists could have different lengths. The problem occurred to me when following this [tutorial](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-lookups.html) so maybe this helps.

Example:

```
#+TBLNAME: the-tbl
| First Line                |  1 |
| Second Line               |  2 |
| Third Line                |  3 |
| *some additional lines*   |    |
| Fifth Line                |  5 |
|                           |  6 |
| Seventh Line              |  7 |
| *another additional line* |    |
| Ninth Line                |  9 |
| Tenth Line                | 10 |
| Eleventh Line             | 11 |

| First Line   |   1 |   1 | OK                                                       |
| Third Line   |   3 |   3 | OK                                                       |
| No Line      | nil | nil | OK                                                       |
| Fifth Line   |   6 |   5 | Wrong because Line 4 has no value thus it is one shorter |
| Seventh Line |   7 |   7 | Only OK, because now both columns have a missing value   |
| Tenth Line   |  11 |  10 | Wrong again, because column 2 had another missing value  |
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-lookup-first $1 '(remote(the-tbl, @1$1..@>$1)) '(remote(the-tbl, @1$2..@>$2)))
```

Are there any ways to select columns like this, but maintaining empty cells? Or is there a better function than org-lookup-first for what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the calculations in `E` mode.  **The last two characters in the `TBLFM` line is `;E`**

```
If you ~C-c C-c~ on the first table, you get the second table.

#+TBLNAME: the-tbl
| First Line                |  1 |
| Second Line               |  2 |
| Third Line                |  3 |
| *some additional lines*   |    |
| Fifth Line                |  5 |
|                           |  6 |
| Seventh Line              |  7 |
| *another additional line* |    |
| Ninth Line                |  9 |
| Tenth Line                | 10 |
| Eleventh Line             | 11 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-lookup-first $1 '(remote(the-tbl, @1$1..@>$1)) '(remote(the-tbl, @1$2..@>$2)));E

#+TBLNAME: the-tbl
| First Line                |  1 |  1 |
| Second Line               |  2 |  2 |
| Third Line                |  3 |  3 |
| *some additional lines*   |    |    |
| Fifth Line                |  5 |  5 |
|                           |  6 |  6 |
| Seventh Line              |  7 |  7 |
| *another additional line* |    |    |
| Ninth Line                |  9 |  9 |
| Tenth Line                | 10 | 10 |
| Eleventh Line             | 11 | 11 |
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-lookup-first $1 '(remote(the-tbl, @1$1..@>$1)) '(remote(the-tbl, @1$2..@>$2)));E
```

---

See

```
(info "(org) Formula syntax for Calc")
```

or

[Formula syntax for Calc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html)

**`E`: If and how to consider empty fields.**

**Without `E` empty fields in range references are suppressed so that the Calc vector or Lisp list contains only the non-empty fields.  With `E` the empty fields are kept.**  For empty fields in ranges or empty field references the value `nan` (not a number) is used in Calc formulas and the empty string is used for Lisp formulas.  Add `N` to use 0 instead for both formula types.  For the value of a field the mode `N` has higher precedence than `E`.

Comment: Ah, tranks for that! Do you know when (in which org version) this E mode has been added?  I think in the past empty cells where not ignored (eg given as empty strings in formulas).